# Steam Controller and Non-Steam GTA V

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-v, controllers

I have a non-Steam version of GTA V (PC), and I cannot get the Steam controller to work in GTA V.  I can't get the Steam overlay to work in GTA V, either.

I've Google'd this for hours, and there are literally about half a dozen other people who have mentioned this and no working fixes.

I added GTA V as a non-Steam game.  I launched Big Picture Mode (BPM) and updated the controller's firmware.  I launched GTA V through BPM.  Nothing.

Has anyone figured out how to get this to work?  I'm extremely disappointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after hours of searching here's what I did!

I found this video that explains that you need to set GTA V to run as Administrator, but you *also* need to set Steam to run as administrator.  It will warn you that you're running in "compatibility mode" but that only applies if you set it to run in some other version of Windows compatibility mode.  All you're going to do is set it to run as Administrator.  I set it to run as Admin for all users to  be sure.

Also, I unplugged my Saitek X-55 Rhino.  I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it just yet, but to be safe I did so and restarted Steam and GTA V.  FINALLY I have the Steam overlay enabled and I can use my Steam Controller!   Yes!

I hope this helps.